# Passing several query parameters to a GET endpoint in .netcore web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, controller

I have an application where there will be several parameters passed to my endpoint for searching, these parameters are not defined because they are dynamically generated so i cannot map it to a specific model. What would be the best way to map any query parameters into my GET endpoint?

```
[HttpGet]
public CustomResponse GetResults({something here that will map the parameters?})
{
    //perhaps a dictionary? a collection of some sort? 
}
```

Then I need to get all those keys and values and search the database for anything containing that and as i said it could be anything.

So I could pass something like?

```
/api/Merchandise/GetResults?sku=30021&cupsize=medium&color=red&location=south& {and all the dynamic fields which could be anything}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpRequest` object has `Query` property that is an `IQueryCollection` and holds all passed query parameters.

In other words, in your action method you may do:

```
[HttpGet]
public CustomResponse GetResults()
{
    var queryParams = HttpContext.Request.Query;

    // directly get by name
    var value1 = queryParams["parameter_name"];
    // or queryParams.TryGetValue()

    foreach (var parameter in queryParams)
    {
        string name = parameter.Key;
        object value = parameter.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map it to JObject, which is like a Dictionary.

Don't forget:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```